# Audio not working after switching to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone, mate, eeepc

I have some audio problems in my netbook (Asus eeepc). I used to work with lubuntu 14.04 and audio was perfectly working after pulseaudio installation. I decided to change to Ubuntu Mate 15.10. After installation the system "recognizes" the internal speakers as headphones and therefore sound is automatically off. When I plug in the headphones I can listen the audio but as soon as I take the jack out I will not listen any longer. Everytime either I log out of the session or shut down the netbook I will have to change Alsamixer settings (Changing Headphone MM into 00, and increasing the volume). I also have some problems with the microphone. I did not find a solution to make changes permanent after restarting the system. Have you got any suggestions? 
I tried with Pulseaudio pavucontrol, alsamixergui and others but same result. Finally I read about many problems similar to mine in the upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04, however the solutions which worked for others were not appropriate for my case